# Sending form data to another laptop in the same wifi connection

Tags: php, tcp, udp, ip, fsockopen

I have a php application in development. The first laptop will act as the customer while the second laptop will act as the seller. The customer will fill out a form about an order in the online shop and I need to send the order information to the other laptop. Both laptops will be connected to the same wifi connection.
How do I implement this? How to send? How to receive? I'm gonna go crazy. I've read about udp, tcp, fsockets, but there's really no clear sample on how to use these.

Comment: I'm assuming you are making a site with php. Run your site using XAMPP or any other Apache distribution and learn about GET and POST.

Comment: how do i do that? my professor said I need to send the data using the ip address of the receiving laptop.